# Symfony cache:clear command triggers warning

Tags: php, symfony, caching, twig

Running the Symfony2 cache:clear command on an empty cache keeps triggering errors.

We don't have `auto_reload` defined in the config file so it uses the debug value.
In development this will be true, in production this will be false.
when `auto_reload` is true it works fine since it doesn't try to include files from the cache.

- Symfony's cache warmup command will use the `CacheWarmerAggregate`
- One of the warmers is the `TemplateCacheCacheWarmer`
- In the `warmUp` method of `TemplateCacheCacheWarmer` it will try to load the template if its engine is twig, calling `loadTemplate` of `Twig_Environment`
- Inside `Twig_Environment` the cache generates a random key and if `autoReload` is false it will call `$this->cache->load`
- The `load` function in `Twig_Cache_Filesystem` uses a supressed include_once which triggers a warning that the file could not be found because no cache has been written yet

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add `$debug = error_get_last();` or whatever you want to use to debug the error after the `$this->cache->load($key);` in `Twig_Environment::loadTemplate`
2. Delete contents of the cache folder
3. Run app/console cache:clear --env=prod
4. $debug will contain an error saying `include_once(): Failed opening '/path/to/symfony/app/cache/local__pro_/twig/fb/fb29d5e893de121cf8bbf19b167578b6777f301a00055526687e21c.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')`

Comment: I think you should post this on [Symfony's GitHub issues page](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues), it will have better visibility there.

Comment: @RaduMurzea I did consider it but symfony's [bug report guidlines](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/bugs.html) suggest asking on stackoverflow first. Since I encountered this problem I found it was caused by a recent change in twig - [this pull request](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/1840). It can still be avoided in symfony by running cache:clear with the `-no-optional-warmers` option.

Comment: We're facing the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, I think this behavior is known to the developers. I read somewhere that the problem was overzealous logging that results in these errors being noticed and that they're safe to ignore but I can't remember where

Comment: Symfony 4.1 and problem still there.